How to preserve Android app permissions after clearing it's data?
I need to preserve app permissions after clearing it's data (since it's users are not skilled in using Android);
I tried to google how to do that but I can't find an answer which would satisfy me...
I'm aware of Auto-Backup, but I need to solve that without Google Play...

Fortunately you can not add permissions to your app from your app without asking user to do this

the thing is, when app data are cleared, it gets their permissions revoked and the user needs to grant them once again (which I don't want it to happen)

The thing is, if this would be possible than obviously there would be no sense in permissions at all


I need to preserve app permissions after clearing it's data

Create your own custom version of the Android OS that offers this capability. Install that version of the OS on whatever hardware that you support, then distribute that hardware to your users.
Otherwise, what you are seeking is not an option.

when app data are cleared, it gets their permissions revoked and the user needs to grant them once again (which I don't want it to happen)

If they have the skill to get into the Settings app, find your app, and clear data, they have the skill to grant permissions again.
